# Why user control declarations gets deleted after making a change in the designer?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

We have a legacy application, the main form has a lot of controls (buttons, grids, comboboxes, etc). For a new feature a user controls was created and then added to the main form. And it works correctly, the problem here is that when we want to add somo other controls to the main form or modify any property at design time, all the references to the user control in the Designer.cs file are automatically deleted, and we need to add the missing code manually. These is the code that gets deleted:

```
this.UserControl = new Namespace.NewUserControl();
this.ContainerPanel.SuspendLayout();
this.ContainerPanel.Controls.Add(this.UserControl);

this.UserControl.Property1 = 1;
// All the properties set at design time
this.UserControl.PropertyN = N;

this.ContainerPanel.ResumeLayout(false);
private Namespace.NewUserControl UserControl;
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: The designer.cs file is meant to be generated after any change to the designer. The class itself is partial though, so if you want to persist some changes to it, you can probably add another file with partial and the code you wrote in this question

Comment: You should post the Constructor of this UserControl, specify whether it uses a custom CodeDomSerializer, custom Designers etc., if you override *sensible* methods, as `OnHandleCreated()`, `OnLayout()` etc., what code you run in the overrides, whether you have `static` declarations (of any kind), whether you perform specific actions related to the child Controls, the Parent Control or the TopLevelControl. If you have decorated the class object with some *special attributes*, post those, too.

Comment: Don't edit the designer code file manually. It is supposed to represent what you do in the designer. If you want to adda  user control to the form, do it in the designer and that will update the designer code file.